# Oracle Apex Clear cache post processing

Tags: oracle-apex

Can we add the option to clear unwanted cache in page processing, ex: when a button is pressed, the process happens lets say its simple insert.

Can we add a clear cache for page logic and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

There is a page process of type "Clear Session State" that you can use for this purpose. It has different types - for your purpose the type "Clear all items on the current page" seems the most appropriate.

However... typically cache should only be cleared when a page is rendered - it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.